# Change Password Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following functions to change a password and display the users profile, but upon submitting the form instead of being redirected to the `'profile/'` page I get an error saying `The view core.views.change_password didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`, why is this?

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm,    PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data= request.POST, user = request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user) #this function keeps the user logged in afte they change their password
            # request.user could not have been passed in because that would pass in 'AnonymousUser', however
            #form.user gets the user who was filling in the form and passes it to the function
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user)
        args = {'form': form}  # gives access to the form in the template
        return render(request, 'core/change_password.html', args)

def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user} #
    return render(request, 'core/profile.html', args)
```

Note: The profile page does work on other parts of the site, for example after logging in the user is redirected to their profile page with no issue.

Comment: What happens when form isn't valid ? Answer: Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the last two lines out of the `else` block. This way, you will return a response for POST requests when the form is not valid.

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data= request.POST, user = request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user)
    args = {'form': form}  # gives access to the form in the template
    return render(request, 'core/change_password.html', args)
```